# how to check from what crossdomain iframe the message (postMessage) came?

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain, postmessage

I know that the `MessageEvent` has `source` property which is the window object that send the message. Now how to having this information check what iframe in the main document (and of course within the main document on message arrival) was the source of that particular message ? Is only available option to check `location.href` on the `event.source` window object and then loop all the iframes to check which is matching ? What if there are iframes with the same source url in the main document ?

Answer (score 3):

Iterate over all the iframes on a page and do an identity comparison on their `window` objects.

```
window.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    if(e.origin === 'https://www.example.com') {
        var iframes = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');

        for(var i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
            if(e.source === iframes[i].contentWindow) {
                // Do stuff with iframes[i]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I believe this works in all modern browsers; I'd be interested to hear if anyone has problems with it.

Comment: Nice solution! Works in Firefox too.

Answer (score 2):

If you try to read the `location.href` property of a cross-domain iframe/window, this will throw an exception since it violates the same-origin policy. You can **write** to that property, but you cannot **read**. And even if that would work, you would have the problem with multiple iframes with the same URL problem, as you guessed.

Anyway, what you can do is - establish a protocol for some kind of message sending confirmation. In other words, in the iframe that receives a message X you would iterate over all the iframes in the parent document and send a message to each iframe asking *"Did you send me message X?"* and you would program all the iframes to respond to such questions. Of course, you would have to attach unique IDs to all messages so that you would know which iframe acknowledged that it sent which message.

I think that you have to think about why the receiver of the message needs to know who the sender was, and why it is not enough for you to know just the reference to that sender (`event.source`)? If there is some information known to the sender - then the sender can just send this information in the message in the first place.

Comment: Not if you don't have control of the sender, of course. I have pages with several hidden Vimeo embeds on each. When the user clicks the button to display one of them, I need to wait until I've received a "ready" message from the frame before sending a "play" message to it. But if your answer is correct, I have no way to know which iframe said it was ready! That seems like a pretty big oversight to me; I can't figure out how it improves security in any way, and not having control of the iframe page is an incredibly standard use case.

Answer (score 0):

a more efficient way is to pass the iframes each a unique ID on initiation, and make them use that id when posting back to the parent frame.